# Use Ruby on Rails environment config based on URL/Machine Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a RoR3 app with multiple environment configs, development.rb, test.rb and production.rb.

Is there a way I can instruct the application to used a specific config based on a value in the URL or machine name??

For instance if the machine name contains "dev", then use development.rb.

**Edit**

If that is not possible, is there a way I can access the request URL from the application.rb or environment.rb files maybe.  If so, I could probably use a regex on the URL to determine and set the environment settings dynamically within if blocks.

In the end, we'll end up having many more than just 3 environments, all with certain differences.  So I need a very flexible way to set the config.

Comment: Is this related to deploying code? [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org) can help address roles and environments for multiple server environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. By the time the rails app is running (and can look at the machine name) it's already picked an environment. Unless you hack the boot script...

It'd be much easier to just put the environment into the startup-command-line for each machine.

Comment: Yes after looking for a solution for some time, it seems you are correct.